# How to implement SelectionEvent in Composite GWT

Tags: java, events, gwt

I am writing a `Composite` widget in GWT, and want for it to implement `HasSelectionHander` and fire a `SelectionEvent` when an element of the composite is selected

So far, I have the following:

```
public class SelectionClass extends Composite implements HasSelectionHandlers<Integer>{

    private final EventBus eventBus = new SimpleEventBus();

    //...   

    private void somethingHappens(int i){
            //How do i fire an event?
    }       

    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addSelectionHandler(SelectionHandler<Integer> handler) {
            return eventBus.addHandler(SelectionEvent.getType(), handler);
    }       

}

public AnotherClass{

    // ...  

    SelectionClass.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Integer> event) {
                    Window.alert(String.valueOf(event.getSelectedItem()));
            }       
    });     

    // ...  
}
```

I am a bit confused about how exactly to implement the firing of the event. Am I right to use an `EventBus` in the SelectionClass (above). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The firing of the event is done through the `EventBus` API, in GWT 2.4 you don't need to instantiate your own instance of the 'EventBus' as you can delegate your `addXXXHandler` methods to the super `Composite` class.

It'd be something like the following:

```
public class SelectionClass extends Composite implements HasSelectionHandlers<Integer>{

    //...   

    private void somethingHappens(int i){
            SelectionEvent.<Integer>fire(this, i);
    }       

    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addSelectionHandler(SelectionHandler<Integer> handler) {
            return super.addHandler(handler, SelectionEvent.getType());
    }       

}
```

Comment: The constructor for `SelectionEvent` is [protected](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/SelectionEvent.html), so I don;t think I can just construct the object as you suggest?

Comment: sorry, was used to work with an version of GWT prior to 2.4. Updated my answer